# auto refresh cache ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, browser-cache

I have a website with a lot of data in it.
I use C# .NET MVC4 for development.
I have a big slow page loading problem when the cache is empty.
currently I'm using a cache that contains all the data that I need and when the cache is on the pages loads right away, but when the cache expires it takes about 10s the page to be fully loaded.

I'm looking for an option to auto refresh the cache when it expires,
I've been searching over goolge, but couldn't find anything in that matter

How is it should be done? 
Or are there other options to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What sort of cache are you using?

Answer (score 6):

You could cache it on the first call with a TTL, let it invalidate, and then the next call will get it and cache it back again.  The problem with this is that you are slowing down your thread while it has to go fetch the data as it is unavailable, and multiple threads will wait for it (assuming you lock the read to prevent flooding).

One way to get around the first load issue is to prime your cache on application start up.  This assures that when your application is ready to be used, the data is already loaded up and will be fast.  Create a quick interface like ICachePrimer { void Prime() }, scan your assemblies for it, resolve them, then run them.

The way I like to get around the empty cache on invalidation issue is to refresh the data before it is removed. To easily do this in .Net, you can utilize the MemoryCache's CacheItemPolicy callbacks.

UpdateCallback occurs before the item is removed, and allows you to refresh the item.
RemovedCallback occurs after the item has been removed.

In the example below, my CachedRepository will refresh the cached item when it is invalidated.  Other threads will continue to receive the "old" value until the refresh completes.

```
public class MyCachedRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _baseRepository;
    private readonly ObjectCache _cache;

    public MyCachedRepository(IMyRepository baseRepository, ObjectCache cache)
    {
        _baseRepository = baseRepository;
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public string GetById(string id)
    {
        var value = _cache.Get(id) as string;

        if (value == null)
        {
            value = _baseRepository.GetById(id);
            if (value != null)
                _cache.Set(id, value, GetPolicy());
        }

        return value;
    }

    private CacheItemPolicy GetPolicy()
    {
        return new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            UpdateCallback = CacheItemRemoved,
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0.1),  //set your refresh interval
        };
    }

    private void CacheItemRemoved(CacheEntryUpdateArguments args)
    {
        if (args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Expired || args.RemovedReason == CacheEntryRemovedReason.Removed)
        {
            var id = args.Key;
            var updatedEntity = _baseRepository.GetById(id);
            args.UpdatedCacheItem = new CacheItem(id, updatedEntity);
            args.UpdatedCacheItemPolicy = GetPolicy();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: http://pdalinis.blogspot.in/2013/06/auto-refresh-caching-for-net-using.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to auto refresh a cache when the keys expire. All caching systems employ passive expiration. The keys are invalidated the first time they are requested after the expiration, not automatically at that exact expiration time.

What you're talking about is essentially a cache that never expires, which is easy enough to achieve. Simply either pass no expiration (if the caching mechanism allows it) or a far-future expiration. Then, your only problem is *refreshing* the cache on some schedule, so that it does not become stale. For that, one option is to create a console application that sets the values in the cache (importantly, without caring if there's something there already) and then use Task Scheduler or similar to schedule it to run at set intervals. Another option is to use something like [Revalee](http://revalee.sageanalytic.com/) to schedule callbacks into your web application at defined intervals. This basically the same as creating a console app, only the code could be integrated into your same website project.

You can also use [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) to perform the scheduling directly within your web application, and could use that to run a console application, hit a URL, whatever. The power of Hangfire is that it allow you pretty much schedule any process you want, but that also means you have to actually provide the code for what should happen, i.e. actually connect with HttpClient and fetch the URL, rather than just telling Revallee to hit a particular URL.